# how can I configure wireshark to capture to not-80 port http request?

Tags: wireshark

with "ip.dst == 10.1.0.199 and http.request", I can listen to http request to 199 with port of 80, but when I start non-80 port http server on 199, wireshark could not capture http request any more.

Could you please give me some point about that?

thanks in advance~~~

Answer (score 1):

You will need to a port configuration: tcp.port == 8080 for example.

That will allow you to capture the traffic. You should then be able to decode the traffic as http.  It is also possible to configure wireshark so the traffic on the non-standard port is automatically parsed as http traffic.

The top results from google using: wireshark capture http non-standard port

should hopefully give you an option that will work for your case.